# Validate ISO 639-2 language codes ​​- Delphi

Tags: regex, validation, delphi, delphi-xe5

How do I validate [ISO 639-2 language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2) with Delphi? I created my regular expression as:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}([-\/][a-zA-Z]{2,3})?
```

This works correctly in php, but in Delphi it does not validate the strings I pass.

Valid strings are:

```
XX
XXX    
XX-XX
XXX-XX
XXX-XXX
XX-XXX

XX/XX
XXX/XX
XXX/XXX
XX/XXX
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an end of string anchor at the end:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}([-\/][a-zA-Z]{2,3})?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kV9xH5/1)